# авто поднятие сервера nodejs

Tags: node.js, сервер

Товарищи, помогите с проблемой. Есть ли какой-то механизм для поднятия nodejs.
 Если приложение упало как его автоматически поднять?

Comment: Нужно выбрать модуль для этого, например [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно выбрать модуль для этого, например [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Но лучше всего, не допускать, чтобы падало всё приложение.
Заверните ваше приложение в `cluster` и запустите несколько воркеров с основным кодом приложения. Родительский процесс оставьте максимально простым, чтобы там нечему было падать.
При падении воркера родительский процесс запускает новый.

Разумеется, оба подхода стоит объединить

---

<sub>Сто лет назад писал обёртку для этого, можете посмотреть для примера: [node-cluster-app](https://github.com/vpArth/node-cluster-app)

*Только не вздумайте использовать его как есть, я тогда только изучал nodejs*</sub>

Comment: вот, мне не понятно было как запускать ноду вне терминала или командной строки. Это получается воркеры юзать надо?

Comment: локально всё понятно npm start и она в терминале крутится, а как на сервере быть?

Comment: Воркеры - это форки основного процесса, они падают, а основной процесс живёт и видит, что кто-то упал. Поэтому он может запустить новый форк.

Comment: Ну без `node app.js` вы не обойдётесь в любом случае. Можно завернуть это в сервис, скажем для `systemd`, чтобы нода при физической перезагрузке сервера запускалась.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. На выходных попробую разобраться

Answer (score 6):

У NodeJS есть модуль [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

Устанавливаете его и в консоли вводите

```
$ forever start script_name.js
```

И тогда скрипт script_name.js запускается без остановки.

Answer (score 3):

1. Модуль **forever** ставится глобально (если локально, то надо ставить **forever-monitor**), плюс вот не забудьте `apt-get install nodejs-legacy`.
2. Создаём лог-файл - `/var/log/FILENAME.log` и пид-файл - `/var/run/FILENAME.pid`
3. И запускаем приложение вот так: `forever start --pidFile /var/run/FILENAME.pid -l /var/log/FILENAME.log -a SCRIPTNAME.js` (но это для пробы, конечно, потом-то надо дэймон замутить и эту команду туда прописать)